# Windows Azure: node.js + mongodb setup cheaply

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure

I am building a chrome extension that needs a backend to store user information. So far, we have been using Firebase, a real-time solution that we can access from the front end. Yet we will need to store approximately 200GB of data so Firebase seems less viable for a startup budget.

We were looking into transitioning  to hosting a node.js app in the cloud and then communicating with a mongodb database. We were looking into Azure for this purpose. Yet it seems the only way to do this is getting MongoLab, which is still really expensive. Isn't there a way to store a lot data in mongodb without incurring in huge costs? For some reason, the SQL databases look way cheaper, which does not make much sense to me.

some links for reference.

SQL pricing:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

mongodb pricing:

https://mongolab.com/plans/pricing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can get Mongo running in Azure. You would simply fire up a new Linux VM and install Mongo and you're off!

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/#Linux

Your question hints that the biggest priority is disk space. Storage in Azure is pretty cheap. Let's imagine you get an A2 instance with 60 GB of space and you run out of space. You can easily attach new disks in Azure and the storage is really cheap.

The classic way to scale Mongo however is to use a replica set, in which case you'll need to pay for more nodes/machines as you add them.

Comment: That's exactly what we were looking for! Thanks so much! Just a couple questions before I officially accept: How does the VM perform? Would it support many users at a time? We'd need this online 24/7 so we need it to be relatively fast and reliable.

Comment: At my current place we're running maybe 20 Linux VM's in Azure. For the most part it's fine. The only problem is that Azure will reboot the machines periodically with little or no notice. The machines will come back after maybe 10 minutes. So make sure all your services etc. will start on boot. If you absolutely need no down time, then look at this: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-manage-availability/#configure-multiple-virtual-machines-in-an-availability-set-for-redundancy

Comment: The documentation link is now different from above https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/manage-availability